# Ember.js - What purpose does Ember.lookup serve

Tags: ember.js

Can anyone tell me what purpose Ember.lookup serves?

It is used to lookup string keys.

An example of its use in the ember source is:

```
if(typeof modelType === "string"){
  return Ember.get(Ember.lookup, modelType);
} else {
  return modelType;
}
```

I can see that it returns a type from a string but I don't see where it is set or what the bigger picture is for its usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ember.lookup` was introduced along with `Ember.imports` and `Ember.exports` as a way to remove the dependency on `window`.

If you are running Ember in the browser, all three values will refer to the `window`, however if you are running without the browser, for instance, through NodeJS or with AMD, you will need to supply values yourself.

See the [commit message](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/305202fa51aca55ce1ff935aa9fb8ebe3da4a0d4) for more information.